# Complicated Regex Pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have the following literal strings that i'm looping through:

```
Some prior text <COMPANY-IDENTIFIER>oranges.txt : 3254323
Some prior text <COMPANY-IDENTIFIER>raisins.txt : 6434422
Some prior text <COMPANY-IDENTIFIER>apples.txt : 932323
```

I'm trying to split the strings on:  `<COMPANY-IDENTIFIER>`, the file name, and the `:`

I believe `<` and `>` are special regex characters and file name changes for each string.

I have used variations of the following pattern to split on:

```
pattern = '<COMPANY-IDENTIFIER>(.*): '  #supposed to detect <COMPANY-IDENTIFIER>apples.txt : , etc
the_number = string.split(pattern)[1]
```

But my pattern isn't working.

Looking for guidance on what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Your regex works here: https://regex101.com/r/OR2ctQ/1

Comment: Here too... https://regexr.com/4vnb3

Comment: `string.split` doesn't take regular expressions as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use regular expressions, `re.split()`, not `str.split()`. Also, remove the parentheses from the pattern:

```
pattern = '<COMPANY-IDENTIFIER>.*: '
re.split(pattern, txt)
#['Some prior text ', '3254323']
```

Comment: Seems the issue here is not so much the pattern, as the pattern actually works. It is the fact he has called `string.split()` instead of `re.split()`

Comment: @PacketLoss True. But, interestingly, even with regex their pattern does not work as expected.

Comment: Indeed, `(.*)` includes `fruit.txt` where as `.*` omits it.

Answer (score 1):

To split at those point you can use the regular expression

```
r' +<|>| *: *'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IJvBJy/1/)

The regular expression reads, "match one or more spaces followed by '<' *or* '>' *or* one or more spaces followed by a colon followed by one or more spaces".

```
"Some prior text <COMPANY-IDENTIFIER>oranges.txt : 3254323"
```

is split into `"Some prior text"`, `"COMPANY-IDENTIFIER"`, `"oranges.txt"` and `"3254323"`.

Comment: is "<" a special regex character?  I saw somewhere that is used in "less than" or "before" patterns.  That would suggest needing to make it a literal where the character is needed (e.g., "\<" or "\>".  No?

Comment: `(?<=...)` and `(?<!...)` define positive and negative lookbehinds. When `"<"` is used elsewhere (as here) it is treated as an ordinary character.